# Docker containers cannot access Tomcat hosted natively on mac

Tags: docker, tomcat, networking, connection, containers

So my Tomcat server is hosted natively in Mac (on port `8081`, or `localhost:8081`), and I have a docker container that wants to connect to this server. I have a docker network due to which my host's IP-Address is `192.168.0.1` for **all the containers**. So, for my container, tomcat's address should be `192.169.0.1:8081`. However any request to this address gives me a "connection refused" message. I have tried many combinations of the Connector String, such as:

```
<Connector port="8081" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443"
               address="0.0.0.0" />
```

And this:

```
<Connector port="8081" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443" />
```

And this too:

```
<Connector port="8081" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443"
               useIPVHosts="true" />
```

However, nothing works. All I get is a "connection refused" message. On the other hand, I have other containers hosted in my computer, the containers are able to interact with each other.

More info: My docker-network is configured like so:

```
[
    {
        "Name": "dockernet",
        "Id": "44e98a6b2460e0619e4cea9e0f997ea9f91b188d708a89dcb7fd92268f22cb9d",
        "Created": "2019-09-26T08:15:41.174785012Z",
        "Scope": "local",
        "Driver": "bridge",
        "EnableIPv6": false,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": {},
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "192.168.0.0/24",
                    "Gateway": "192.168.0.1"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Internal": false,
        "Attachable": false,
        "Ingress": false,
        "ConfigFrom": {
            "Network": ""
        },
        "ConfigOnly": false,
        "Containers": {
            "0fb7a111099bb7b83c72ea8b9b4e72a8f95a8e7d8dc1abb1309627ce491608cf": {
                "Name": "container1",
                "EndpointID": "53dcf78532c28ee2bd95653446c4314f8870af129e20cb638cfe38b4b2db6f4b",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:c0:a8:00:03",
                "IPv4Address": "192.168.0.3/24",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "3ff0b72b5b6261218cc0fce539892afe23bd6e9261a883dce098061f579093da": {
                "Name": "container2",
                "EndpointID": "01740839393bf08947fc6424758bea47fa2ad99ae17ad02e8ea43b6b13fec6ed",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:c0:a8:00:05",
                "IPv4Address": "192.168.0.5/24",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "7b8df79e1358f82247d90926263aec066665882bd9135c01dc45a69be42c7058": {
                "Name": "container3-oracle_oracle_1",
                "EndpointID": "6ef968f757c900b4c9f6bf1b36584269ac77bfb4c67b006686619d059735a4a9",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:c0:a8:00:02",
                "IPv4Address": "192.168.0.2/24",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "aa05aff84ca9eb35df47605c3eb75394a6c4ebc8e722ec19a5e01f9ae488a864": {
                "Name": "container4-rabbit_docker_image_rabbitmq_1",
                "EndpointID": "719cd9e31e8474b86a54996cea37a0d9b0c1bbe110361a562033283464c5dfcd",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:c0:a8:00:04",
                "IPv4Address": "192.168.0.4/24",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "c8be10328a217883a14cbc496802e1e12bdce3de0199aabc53dd980c5d4fe474": {
                "Name": "container5",
                "EndpointID": "f869ee9a0016a3acefb8a68276e04785d141366fe31824797d23b98f6bd0b333",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:c0:a8:00:06",
                "IPv4Address": "192.168.0.6/24",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            }
        },
        "Options": {},
        "Labels": {}
    }
]
```

Basically, containers are easily able to interact with each other. However, tomcat, which is hosted natively in the computer is refusing any request from the containers. (Note: Since I get the message `connection refused`, I am assuming there is nothing wrong with the address, in contrast to the message `couldn't connect to the server`, which probably means that the IP Address of the server is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

One workaround I found to connect to Tomacat on host was to use `docker.for.mac.localhost` instead of `192.168.0.1` for connecting to tomcat.

`mac` above can be replaced with your operating system.

However, still confused on why can my containers not connect to the host on `192.168.0.1`.